# Why I'm Getting NaN?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a budget controller application, I'm getting NaN coming from the value input:

```js
var budgetController = (function() {

})();

var UIController = (function() {

  var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    inputBtn: '.add__btn'
  }

  return {
    getDOMstrings: function() {
      return DOMstrings;
    },
    getInput: {
      type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,
      description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
      value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value)
    }

  }

})();

var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

  var setupEventListeners = function() {
    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();
    document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', addItem);
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        addItem();
      }
    });
  }
  var addItem = function() {
    console.log(UIController.getInput)
  }

  return {
    init: function() {
      setupEventListeners();
    }
  }

})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

I know that the Solution is to cover the getInput object by a function

```js
getInput: function() {
  return {
    type: ...
      description: ...
      value: ...
  }
}
```

but why I'm getting NaN on the value input and not on the other inputs? also why I'm getting NaN not another Error?
and why this is an error isn't my code empty from errors?

Comment: Did you tried to log `document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue)` and check what's the value of that ?

Comment: no, because the DOMstrings is inside the IIFE, the console has no access to the IIFE functions

Comment: @Jonas — No, `DOMstrings.inputType` is (directly) accessed only inside the IIFE

Comment: @Quentin that's ture

Comment: Your `UIController` will be returning the values of those fields _at the moment it was constructed with the IIFE_.   I expect you were looking for something more dynamic than that?

Comment: you can set a default value when value is not there `value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value || 0)` or `value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value) || ''`

Comment: @AZ_ — It seems likely that the OP is looking for the current value of the input and not some default.

Comment: @AZ this is one of the solutions, there are many fixes for that, but what I'm trying to find, is that why it's returning NaN because I think that I didn't commit any mistake

Comment: @Jonas you've already been told twice what the mistake is - i.e. evaluating the `.value` of the three DOM elements just once, on document load, when the IIFE is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading `document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value` when the document loads (at which time the value is probably an empty string — `parseFloat("")` is `NaN`).

You need to read the value property of the input **after** the user has typed something into it.

e.g. when the click event fires

Comment: that's exactly what the code Implements

Comment: @Jonas — No. You read `UIController.getInput` when the click happens. The values inside that object are assigned *when the document loads*.

Comment: @Jonas it doesn't appear to be - the values returned by your `getInput` object will be assigned at the time the `UIController` is created.   You instead need that object to contain functions that are invoked to get the _current_ value (or perhaps implement "getters" if you want it to contain properties that are evaluated on the fly)

Comment: @Jonas : For a simplified example to compare what you are doing and what I say you should be doing: https://jsbin.com/goheyowopu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `getInput` is being populated at the moment that the IIFE is executed, and not at the point at which the value is required.

The simplest fix is to replace `getInput` with a *function* that returns the desired object:

```
getInput: function() {
    return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,
        description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value)
    }
}
```

Comment: it's something related to execution context and the stack

Comment: thank you Alnitak, your answer was the solution

Comment: @Jonas upvote, then, please!

Answer (score -1):

Check the input of parseFloat(). 99% this is not a parsable input. Here lies your error if I have to bet.
Still you can check this kind of things yourself simply opening the code in a debugger.

Comment: I tried to remove the pareFloat function from the code but still not working